# Nested TSQL to Calculate a Value and Assign a Classification

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have 6 Questions which each have 5 choices. Each choice is assigned an integer value from 1-5.
5 is the highest value.  The questions are averaged to yield a risk value eg      (1+2+3+4+5+5)/6= 3.333

The Risk Values are then related to a risk classification. eg 0-1 = 'Negligible'

```
0 <=1 = Negligible
1 <=2 = Minor
2 <=3 = Serious
3 <=4 = Major
4 <=5 = Extreme.
```

The difference is that whenever the highest value is selected. eg Class 5, then Extreme MUST be applied.

```
eg (1+1+1+1+1+5)/6 = 1.667  = "Extreme"
eg (4+4+4+4+4+4)/6 = 4  = "Major"
eg (1+1+1+1+1+1)/6 = 1  = "Negligible"
eg (5+5+5+5+5+5)/6 = 5  = "Extreme"
```

The output is a the average value and the relevant classification.
Hopefully this is easy to interpret.

```
This is the basic logic in JS


// JavaScript source code
var Enviroavg =
    (Math.abs(Number($('#x_EnvERRSoilContVisAssID').val()))
        + Math.abs(Number($('#x_EnvERRSurfWatConAMDID').val()))
        + Math.abs(Number($('#x_EnvERRGroundWatContID').val()))
        + Math.abs(Number($('#x_EnvERRErosionSedimentID').val()))
        + Math.abs(Number($('#x_EnvERRStabSubsID').val()))
        + Math.abs(Number($('#x_EnvERRFailContStructID').val()))
    ) / 6

// Basic Range Classification of Averaged Class Values
if (Enviroavg >= 0 && Enviroavg <= 1) {
    $('#EnvironmentClass').val(Enviroavg);
    $('#EnvironmentAvgRating').val("NEGLIGIBLE");
}
else if (Enviroavg > 1 && Enviroavg <= 2) {
    $('#EnvironmentClass').val(Enviroavg);
    $('#EnvironmentAvgRating').val("MINOR");
}
else if (Enviroavg > 2 && Enviroavg <= 3) {
    $('#EnvironmentClass').val(Enviroavg);
    $('#EnvironmentAvgRating').val("SERIOUS");
}
else if (Enviroavg > 3 && Enviroavg <= 4) {
    $('#EnvironmentClass').val(Enviroavg);
    $('#EnvironmentAvgRating').val("MAJOR");
}


//individual extreme assessments where Any Question Class=5
else if (EnvERRSoilContVisAssID > 4) {
    $('#EnvironmentAvgRating').val("EXTREME");
    $('#EnvironmentClass').val(Enviroavg);}
else if (EnvERRSurfWatConAMDID > 4) {
    $('#EnvironmentAvgRating').val("EXTREME");
    $('#EnvironmentClass').val(Enviroavg);}
else if (EnvERRGroundWatContID > 4) {
    $('#EnvironmentAvgRating').val("EXTREME");
    $('#EnvironmentClass').val(Enviroavg);}
else if (EnvERRErosionSedimentID > 4) {
    $('#x_EnvironmentRating').val("EXTREME");
    $('#EnvironmentClass').val(Enviroavg);}
else if (EnvERRStabSubsID > 4) {
    $('#EnvironmentAvgRating').val("EXTREME");
    $('#EnvironmentClass').val(Enviroavg);}
else if (EnvERRFailContStructID > 4) {
    $('#EnvironmentAvgRating').val("EXTREME");
    $('#EnvironmentClass').val(Enviroavg);
}
//remaining possibilities and Final Extreme classification
else (Enviroavg > 4 && Enviroavg <= 5) {
    $('#EnvironmentClass').val(Enviroavg);
    $('#EnvironmentAvgRating').val("EXTREME");
}
```

Basic Sql Query

```
SELECT        TOP (100) PERCENT SiteIDFKRISK, CASE WHEN SiteEnvRiskLikelihoodID = 0 THEN 'INVALID' WHEN SiteEnvRiskLikelihoodID > 0 AND SiteEnvRiskLikelihoodID <= 1 THEN 'NEGLIGIBLE' WHEN SiteEnvRiskLikelihoodID > 0 AND
                          SiteEnvRiskLikelihoodID <= 1 AND E1 = 5 OR
                         E2 = 5 OR
                         E3 = 5 OR
                         E4 = 5 OR
                         E5 = 5 OR
                         E6 = 5 THEN 'EXTREME' WHEN SiteEnvRiskLikelihoodID > 1 AND SiteEnvRiskLikelihoodID <= 2 THEN 'MINOR' WHEN SiteEnvRiskLikelihoodID > 1 AND SiteEnvRiskLikelihoodID <= 2 AND E1 = 5 OR
                         E2 = 5 OR
                         E3 = 5 OR
                         E4 = 5 OR
                         E5 = 5 OR
                         E6 = 5 THEN 'EXTREME' WHEN SiteEnvRiskLikelihoodID > 2 AND SiteEnvRiskLikelihoodID <= 3 THEN 'SERIOUS' WHEN SiteEnvRiskLikelihoodID > 2 AND SiteEnvRiskLikelihoodID <= 3 AND E1 = 5 OR
                         E2 = 5 OR
                         E3 = 5 OR
                         E4 = 5 OR
                         E5 = 5 OR
                         E6 = 5 THEN 'EXTREME' WHEN SiteEnvRiskLikelihoodID > 3 AND SiteEnvRiskLikelihoodID <= 4 THEN 'MAJOR' WHEN SiteEnvRiskLikelihoodID > 3 AND SiteEnvRiskLikelihoodID <= 4 AND E1 = 5 OR
                         E2 = 5 OR
                         E3 = 5 OR
                         E4 = 5 OR
                         E5 = 5 OR
                         E6 = 5 THEN 'EXTREME' WHEN SiteEnvRiskLikelihoodID > 4 THEN 'EXTREME' WHEN SiteEnvRiskLikelihoodID > 4 AND E1 = 5 OR
                         E2 = 5 OR
                         E3 = 5 OR
                         E4 = 5 OR
                         E5 = 5 OR
                         E6 = 5 THEN 'EXTREME' END AS SiteEnvRiskLikelihoodID, CASE WHEN SiteSafetyConsequenceLikelihoodID IS NULL 
                         THEN 'Invalid' ELSE CASE WHEN SiteSafetyConsequenceLikelihoodID = 0 THEN 'INVALID' ELSE CASE WHEN SiteSafetyConsequenceLikelihoodID <= 4 THEN 'MINOR' ELSE CASE WHEN SiteSafetyConsequenceLikelihoodID <= 6
                          THEN 'SERIOUS' ELSE CASE WHEN SiteSafetyConsequenceLikelihoodID <= 8 THEN 'MAJOR' ELSE CASE WHEN SiteSafetyConsequenceLikelihoodID > 8 THEN 'EXTREME' END END END END END END AS SiteSafetyConsequenceLikelihoodID,
                          EnvERRSoilContVisAssID, EnvERRSurfWatConAMDID, EnvERRGroundWatContID, EnvERRErosionSedimentID, EnvERRStabSubsID, EnvERRFailContStructID, SafetySRRLocationID, SafetySRRLanduseID, 
                         SafetySRRAccessibilityID, SafetySRRVisitationID, SafetySRRBarriersEntryID, SafetyConsequenceID, SiteEnvRiskLikelihoodID AS EnvRiskValue, SiteSafetyConsequenceLikelihoodID AS SafetyRiskValue, E1, E2, E3, E4, E5, E6, 
                         S1, S2, S3, S4, S5, S6
```

Comment: Sample data is best served as [DDL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_definition_language) + [DML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_manipulation_language). Please [edit] your question to include it, your current attempt and your desired results. For more details, [read this.](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2976/help-me-write-this-query-in-sql)

Comment: `CASE MAX(answer) WHEN 5 THEN 'Extreme' WHEN 4 THEN 'Major' ...`?

Comment: Hi Geospatial, welcome to SO. I guess your post, at this moment, is 'too broad'. I miss a question in your text. Let us know what are your tried and focus in one sigle thing we can help. May be *"[How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)"* can helps you.

Comment: Are these 6 questions situated in one row *side-by-side* (e.g. `q1 INT, q2 INT, q3 INT...`)? In this case I'd strongly recommed a table design, with a `1:n` related side-table. However: Without knowing your actual structure, answering this question would be wild guessing... Please read [mcve].

Comment: This is the basic logic in JS

Comment: @Geospatial, Your tags are `[sql-server]` and `[tsql]`. Don't understand why the JS-code should help... Are you looking for a `T-SQL` query or do you need help with your JS code? Please try to set up a *stand-alone* sample with some sample data and the expected output. Pleaes read the link I provided above.

Comment: This is the basic logic in JS. attached to the bottom of the original question.  @Shnugo Yes they are queried side by side. I will attach the current sql view sample to the original post.

Comment: @Shnugo I am really looking at implementing the solution as SQL. The JS is just the current logic which needs to be applied to SQL if possible. I have it basically working in SQL which I probably just need to work on to get it right.

Comment: @Lamu thankyou for the suggestion I will look at this one also.

Comment: hi @Geospatial, I voted to close your question. I think this question only helps to you. To post useful questions try to write a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). To post JS code in an SQL question don't seems like a good idea, neither to work with a lot of custom fields.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you needed to think about how you are going to store all these details in the database. Seriously, you weren't going to hard-code all these values into SQL like you did with JS, weren't you? What if business will decide to expand or modify the list of ratings, at some later point? What if they would like to have a UI to do that without attracting a developer?

Below is a simplified setup, based on table variables. Note that normally everyone here expects you to provide one - if you are going to use an answer in an actual LOB application, putting some effort towards receiving such an answer usually helps. It can be a fiddle link, or an initialisation code like the one below, it doesn't really matter.

First, the ratings:

```
-- Risk classifier
declare @Ratings table (
  MinValue money not null,
  MaxValue money not null,
  Name sysname not null unique,
  IsOverride bit not null default 0,
  primary key (MinValue, MaxValue)
);

-- Sample data
insert into @Ratings (MinValue, MaxValue, Name, IsOverride)
values
  (0, 1, 'Negligible', 0),
  (1, 2, 'Minor', 0),
  (2, 3, 'Serious', 0),
  (3, 4, 'Major', 0),
  (4, 5, 'Extreme', 1);
```

This approach allows much greater flexibility in case business will decide to change / expand their logic at some later point. The `IsOverride` column should be set to `1` for ratings that, if present among answers, should take precedence over averages.

Next, a sample answer table:

```
-- Answers to questions - sample
declare @Answers table (
  EntityId int not null,
  QuestionId int not null,
  AnswerValue money not null,
  primary key (EntityId, QuestionId)
);

insert into @Answers (EntityId, QuestionId, AnswerValue)
values
  (1, 1, 1),
  (1, 2, 0),
  (1, 3, 5),
  (1, 4, 1),
  (2, 1, 0),
  (2, 2, 4),
  (2, 3, 3),
  (2, 4, 2);
```

It is probably more complex in your actual system, but all the necessary details are already here.

With this, the query comes out as rather trivial:

```
-- The query
select s.EntityId, s.AvgRating, ra.Name as [RiskClassifier],
  s.MaxRating, rm.Name as [OverrideClassifier], rm.IsOverride
from (
  select q.EntityId, avg(q.AnswerValue) as [AvgRating], max(q.AnswerValue) as [MaxRating]
  from @Answers q
  group by q.EntityId
) s
  -- Simple joins to get average and maximum ratings
  inner join @Ratings ra on s.AvgRating > ra.MinValue and s.AvgRating <= ra.MaxValue
  inner join @Ratings rm on s.MaxRating > rm.MinValue and s.MaxRating <= rm.MaxValue
order by s.EntityId;
```

With an output such as this, you can easily create a total rating (using `case`), if detailed information isn't necessary.

Comment: Thankyou Roger I will do some testing and see if I can adapt it to my scenario